# Fazer uma ação com clique no js

Tags: javascript, css, animação, click

Eu estou a um bom tempo tentando fazer com que eu pudesse iniciar uma animação de sprites após um clique mas já tentei de tudo no js e não consegui, se alguém puder dar um norte já ajudaria muito, estudo por conta própria e ainda não peguei o jeito do js.

```js
('#game-board').hide()

function toggleText() {
  var x = document.getElementById("container1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --pixel-size: 2, 9;
}

body {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background-color: cornsilk;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  color: #ffff;
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 60px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #4e7fda;
  transition: ease-out 0.3s;
  font-size: 2rem;
  outline: none;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 300px 0 0 0 #123f95;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

.game-board {
  width: 80%;
  height: 920px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.Character {
  right: 70%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 78px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Character_spritesheet:hover {
  -webkit-animation: play 1s steps(2) infinite;
  width: calc(0px * var(--pixel-size));
  position: absolute;
}

.pixelart {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(1px, 0, 0)
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="\proj\scriptp.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>PortDig</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container1">
    <div class="container">
      <button onclick="toggleText()" class="btn-1">Iniciar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal" class="game-board">
    <div class="Characterbt"></div>
    <div class="Character">
      <img class="Character_spritesheet pixelart" src="https://i.postimg.cc/prZXNrRC/corP.png" alt="Character">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dj576q9p/26/#&togetherjs=ltyUJwuUsG

Comment: Somos um Q&A, um catalogo de perguntas e respostas detalhadas, objetivas e específicas cujo a intenção é permitir a outros usuários, hoje e no futuro, que por meio de fermentas de automação encontrem soluções a problemas análogos aos que tiver. Da forma que está formulada a pergunta só o atende não sendo possível ser reaproveitada. Queremos que se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão o ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045), [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Essa função "toggleText()" pelo que to vendo só vai mostrar ou esconder o que tiver contido dentro no conteiner1, no caso, o próprio botão. Porque você referenciou o id dentro da função como "conteiner1".

No caso, imagino que você deseje esconder/mostrar a animação de sprite que está fora do conteiner1, no "game-board".

Creio que deva trocar o id na função para o id do elemento que deseja modificar ao clicar.

Dessa maneira aqui:

```
function toggleText() {
   var x = document.getElementById('id_da_animação');
   if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Isso já deve resolver.

Porém mais interessante do que isso, eu sugiro que você adicione um argumento de id à função, assim você poderá reutilizar a mesma função pra mostrar ou esconder em outras coisas.

Ficaria assim:

no JS:

```
function toggleText(id) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id);
   if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

no HTML

```
<button onclick="toggleText('id_da_animação')" class="btn-1">Iniciar</button>
```